# How to correct settings composer for autoload psr-4?

Tags: composer-php

I use composer for autoloading classes but autoload didn't work. My structure of project looks like like this:
Commandos:
   src:
    here is located php classes
inside commandos folder composer json file.

```
{
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Commandos\\": "/src"}
    }
}
```

In every class I use namespace like this `namespace Commandos\Some;` and `require _autoload.php`
Where is I was mistake?

Comment: Please give the exact error message you get for an example class. Where (in which directory) is this class located in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it my mistake.
I should use in composer.json 
{

```
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"commandos\\": "src"}
    }
}
```

and in every my class in folder `src` use namespace begin from `namespace commandos;`